# Java: What is the proper way to import dowloaded packages (folder structure etc)

Tags: java, package

I'm making my first steps with Java, and I'm trying to make a simple program that uses the [Datamuse4J handler](https://github.com/sjblair/Datamuse4J) to find similar words, rhyming words, etc.

I've downloaded the file from GitHub, unzipped it, and I see the folder structure as follows:

[image]

I'm not sure how to proceed from this point on, to use Datamuse4J in my own program. I've copied the datamuse folder (containing DatamuseQuery.java and JSONParse.java) in the same folder as my program, then used `import datamuse.*;` which returned no errors when compiling. But when I tried to use a piece of the code (example follows)

```
public String findSimilarEndsWith(String word, String endLetter) {
        String s = word.replaceAll(" ", "+");
        return getJSON("http://api.datamuse.com/words?rd="+s+"&sp=*"+endLetter);
}
```

I get a symbol not found error for getJSON on line 3. I assumed that I needed to also include the contents of the  lib folder (that is, quick-json-1.0.2.3.jar) but I don't know how to do that - if indeed that is the problem.

Any advice? I understand this is a bit generic question (and there are similar ones which I've tried to study) but sometimes it's easier to learn something with an example you try to become familiar with

Comment: *I'm making my first steps with Java,*?? start form hello world program

Comment: It seems that the op would know how to write a simple program - he's just asking how to use external libraries, which is a perfectly legitimate question IMO (although probably already answered on SO).

Comment: I agree. When you make your first steps, make **first** steps. Trying to use a 3rd party library for json parsing and query work ... rather sounds like *hurdle racing*, not like first steps.

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more context for that snippet - is that inside a class that extends something from DataMuse? If not, then of course getJSON will not be defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use functions of DatamuseQuery.java i.e.findSimilar, findSimilarStartsWith, findSimilarEndsWith etc. you need to create an instance of class DatamuseQuery, then you can use all the function of DatamuseQuery class.

create a file Test.java as following..

```
import datamuse.*;
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         DatamuseQuery dQuery = new DatamuseQuery();

         String s = dQuery.findSimilarEndsWith("personal", "g");

         System.out.println(s+"\n\n");
         System.out.println(dQuery.findSimilarStartsWith("personal", "t"));
    }
}
```

Even if you want to add quick-json-1.0.2.3.jar in your project. Here are the steps:

1. Open your IDE
2. Right click on project name.
3. Go to properties.
4. Go to java build path (In left menu)
5. click on libraries tab.
6. Select add external jars.

   Navigate to the path of external jar in this case quick-json-1.0.2.3.jar. and click ok.

Answer (score 0):

check your build path whether it has all needed library files. If some jars are missing add it. 
If still your problem is not solved, then paste your exception here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to java

To answer your question quickly, since you just copy pasted Datamuse4J code, it would report error because you don't have the method called getJSON()

I suggest you look up some simple tutorials before trying too far ahead, simple tutorial like: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/ gives some basic knowledge of Java